# How to add template ASP.NET MVC Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates

I bought a HTML template in Themeforest. But I'm new with ASP.NET MVC. How to add template to my project in Visual Studio 2013 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you will have to copy the html content from the template to the Layout.cshtml. The Content you want to show common to all the pages like MasterPage which includes Header, Menu, Footer.

2) if the home page contains slider then you will have to use it in Index view.

3) insert your controls in the html in the razor view.

Like this you would have to create your pages with layout as masterpage